# How to align 2 images next to eachother with text underneath

Tags: html, css

I have been trying for quite some time to align this in HTML.

I have two images with a piece of string underneath each image.

[image: Current layout]

I would like to have the images directly next to each other, left and right, with a gap between the two images, but the text is still directly underneath the image; I can't figure it out.

Here is the code I have:

```css
.container {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 7.5%;
  font-family: 'JelleeBold';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

img {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1"><img src="D:\DesktopStuff\Programming\Premier League Predictions\junk\Dark Pink Morning Routine Tutorial YouTube Thumbnail (1).png" alt="">
    <p>Week-by-Week Prediction</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item2"><img src="D:\DesktopStuff\Programming\Premier League Predictions\junk\Dark Pink Morning Routine Tutorial YouTube Thumbnail (2).png" alt="">
    <p>Season Prediction</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: flexbox or grid. both will work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

1. Don’t use d drive link in src:)
2. You can use flexbox system
3. Display: flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center; gap: (your value)
4. The above three css tick is very useful
5. You can Use flexbox in flexbox

Comment: way too broad. Would suite as comment but not as an answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).